# log4j Warning : No appenders found

Tags: log4j

I have the following log4.properties :

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN,console
log4j.rootCategory=debug,A1,D
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %x %c - %m%n

log4j.appender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.D.File=c:/opt/logs/MyLogs.log
log4j.appender.D.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.D.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %x %c - %m%n
```

I am linking it to my project using Java option "-Dlog4j.configuration=c:\opt\config\log4j.properties"

In my Java code I import log4j.Logger and then instantiate it :

```
 public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("testServlet.class");
```

However I am still getting log4j warnings and the log file is not getting generated :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (testServlet.class).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The file name should be log4j.properties. And the file should be located one of the folders in the classpath.

In Eclipse, I have also tried many options but the best solution in Eclipse is to create another 'source folder' in your project and put the `log4j.properties` file in the directory. As all the source folders are in the classpath, the Log4j system will locate your configuration file.